# Can pm2 automatically restart a script that end?

Tags: node.js, grpc, pm2, restart, grpc-node

I made a gRPC client in node and i start it through pm2 with a simple:

`pm2 start --name myAppName`

The gRPC client have some listener on.data, on.error on.end etc

All works well but sometimes the gRPC server trigger the on.end with an error and then the script stop.

`Error: 13 INTERNAL: Received RST_STREAM with code 2 (Internal server error)`

I was expecting that by default pm2 job was to restart in that case but it seem not.

Do i needs to explicitely use a restart strategy like "--exp-backoff-restart-delay=100" when i start the app with pm2 for it to restart automatically in that situation? --watch option is not related here right? its only for file change restart is that correct?

Thanks in advance for the help.